# is it possible to spawn wither skeletons using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The annoying thing about wither skeletons is: There is no way I know of to spawn them in the overworld!

I have determined that there is no way to spawn wither skeletons in the overworld without commands. So that is what I am looking into.

I want to know if there is a command that summons wither skeletons so then I can play around with it a bit and possibly even convert it so I get a wither skeleton spawner.

Also, I already know that if you spawn a skeleton in the nether it has an 80% chance to spawn as a wither skeleton.

Answer (score 12):

You can summon wither skeletons with the following command:

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {SkeletonType:1}
```

Wither skeleton spawner can be created at the block where your feet are with this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Skeleton,SpawnData:{SkeletonType:1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a nether portal, use a spawn egg for skeleton, spawn a skeleton, push it through the nether portal, go through the portal, push the skeleton back into overworld.

Comment: Actually, that is a very good idea.I will probably do it.

Comment: Tested it. Skeletons remain skeletons

Answer (score 0):

Now in the 1.11 update, you can also use the wither skeleton spawn egg.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to the nether and go to nether fortress and use skeleton spawn eggs and 95% you will get wither skeleton! Works for me 1.7.4+

Comment: You don't even have to go to a nether fortress. Just spawn them by your portal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Yes you can do that, but he's looking for cheats.

Answer (score -4):

If you're playing multiplayer ***with the correct plugins***, you can run this command:

```
/spawnmob skeleton:wither
```

Answer (score -4):

Use the /tellraw command to summon it whenever you throw/fire items!

Comment: Give an **example**.